# $slideDown working but not $slideUp also a tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

Hi guys I know its a simple thing but I'm having trouble making this work. Slidedown on click/touch for the nav, the slideUp function isnt working any help? Thanks

Some Code

```
    <div class="nav-container">
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Is Landscape Architecture Right For Me?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/design/index.html" target="_blank">What Is Landscape Architecture?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What Skills Do I Need?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bls.gov/ooh/architecture-and-engineering/landscape-architects.htm" target="_blank">Future Career Prospects (U.S. Labor Department)</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">What Do Landscape Architects Do?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/ContentDetail.aspx?id=22922" target="_blank">Interviews With Leading Landscape Architects</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/2013awards/index.html" target="_blank">ASLA Professional Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/2013studentawards/index.html" target="_blank">ASLA Student Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://astore.amazon.com/a04806-20/detail/0470338458/190-5667858-4355216" target="_blank">Buy the Book:&nbsp;<em>Becoming A Landscape Architect</em></a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Why Is Their Work So Important?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/index.html" target="_blank">Designing Our Future: Sustainable Landscapes</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/videos.html" target="_blank">ASLA Animations</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Where Can I Study?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Picking A School</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Design Intelligence Rankings (2013)</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

$('.nav-pills ul li').on('click touchstart', function() {

    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500);


  });
 $('.nav-pills ul li ul').on('click touchstart', function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(300);

      });


});
```

2nd part of my question is if I can hide tooltips on tablets (ipad) currently a user would have to click for the tooltip then click again to launch the modal

Some Code

```
    <div class="modal-container0">
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg top" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top"   data-original-title="About Columbus Circle" data-target="#myModal_0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

```
     <div class="modal fade right" id="myModal_0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">About Columbus Circle</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="img/0173ColCir_062_c_before.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        <p>Columbus Circle is an awesome project</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div><!--End Modal 1-->
    </div><!--End.modal-content-->
  </div><!--End.modal-dialog-->
</div>
```

Jquery

```
   $(function(){ $('.top').tooltip();});
```

Also here is a link to the site  I'm working on asla.org/yourpath

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please concentrate on a single question - you can simply ask another question about the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks LordT I will keep that in mind for the future. The most pressing issue is the slideDown slideUp functionality.